# How to calculate the average distance between two points in concentric annuli

Tags: geometry, circles, average

I tried to solve this analytically but gave up and ran a simulation. 
I would still like to know if it can be done explicitly.

Consider a circle radially divided into 'zones', so say zone 1 is the annulus that goes from R1 to R2, and zone 2 is the annulus that goes from R3 to R4.
How can I calculate the average distance between two points from zone 1 to zone 2?

I ended up with an equation that looked like:$$d(z1, z2) = \frac{\int_{R1}^{R2}\int_{R3}^{R4}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{r + r' -2\sqrt{r r'}cos(\theta)} dr dr' d\theta}{\int_{R1}^{R2}\int_{R3}^{R4}\int_{0}^{2\pi} dr dr' d\theta}$$

The normal way of solving this is to transform to different polar coordinates, but I don't see how that can work here as the annuli limits become sooooo complicated.

A huge thanks if anyone knows how to do this integral.

Comment: That can't be an average distance; it's got dimensions of the square root of a length. You're missing squares on all the terms inside the square root, and a factor of $r$ and $r'$ from the Jacobians (in both the numerator and the denominator). Or alternatively, if you were trying to confuse us by using the symbol $r$ for what's usually denoted by $r^2$, then the limits on the integrals are wrong. (Unless in "the annulus goes from $R_1$ to $R_2$" you already meant squared radii, which would be even more confusing.)

Comment: Already in the simple case of infinitely thin annuli, the result involves elliptic functions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it is $r$ and not $r^2$ is because you have to transform $r$ to $\sqrt r$ to get an even distribution over the annuli. Otherwise the smaller the annulus the higher the density of points becomes.

I thought it would resolve to an elliptical function problem, but even in the infinitely thin case, the answer still requires the $\theta$ integral and the equation reduces to $\sqrt{ 1 + k^2 sin \theta}$ rather than the usual $\sqrt {1 - k^2 sin \theta}$, soil I wasn't sure that it was an elliptical function anyway.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Sorry, not an answer but I couldn't seem to comment on the question!

Comment: Sorry, not an answer, but I wasn't allowed to add a comment to the above comments!

Comment: Welcome to our site!